# controller and routes doesn't generate the index.php I'm using laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4

I am a newbie at laravel. I have a problem about rooting and views. I am following a tutorial. But the output with the tutorial and my output are not the same.
when i insert this at address bar localhost/laravel/2nd_project/public/authors, i am not generating the index.php which supposed to be have a output just like the tutorial

here is the controllers/authors.php

```
<?php
  class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller{
      public $restful = true;

  public function get_index(){
      return View::make('authors.index');
   }
}
```

app/routes.php

```
<?php
   Route::get('/', function()
   {
     return View::make('hello');
    });

    Route::get('authors',array('uses'=>'Authors_Controller@get_index'));
```

views/authors/index.php

```
<h1>Hi User!!</h1>
```

Comment: This is the views/authors/index.php

<h1>Hi User!!</h1>

Comment: What do you get? Was your Laravel installation successful? Have you seen this? https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BLYFfmLCAAEHcZL.png

Comment: Yes, I've seen that and it is successful, actually i have migrated and create a database using schema.

Comment: But do you get any errors? Whay do you see? What do you mean with "i am not generating the index.php"? Index php is already there you don't have to generate it.

Comment: If you are following a tutorial, why is your code in Laravel 3 style?

Comment: Could you try like this Route::get('authors','Authors_Controller@get_index');

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: I've tried doing that before i posted here Saravana, i guess i need to review the codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're following the tutorial based on Laravel 3. In Laravel 4, things have changed. In laravel 4, the controllers name must follow the pattern `SomethingController`, so the filename for your controller must be `AuthorsController.php` and the class name muse be `AuthorsController`.

So, inside of controllers directory, you'll have a file named `AuthorsController.php` which will be like:

```
<?php
  class AuthorsController extends BaseController {
    public function getIndex()
    {
        return View::make('authors.index');
    }
}
```

Also, if you need to have a file named `BaseController.php` with the class `BaseController`, if you're extending `BaseController` from the `AuthorsController`.

In the routes file you can do the following:

```
Route::get('authors', array('uses'=>'AuthorsController@getIndex'));
```

If you want RESTful controllers in Laravel 4, you can read more about it in the official documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Comment: Thanks for the info, but still it has the same problem. 404 not found

Comment: Have you enabled the `mod_rewrite` plugin in Apache?

Comment: No, I am using wamp server, where can i find that?

Comment: Left click on Wamp icon in the system tray. Go to `Apache` >> `Apache Modules` and click on `rewrite module` to check it. You might need to scroll down on the list to see the `rewrite module`. Then wait until the server is restarted.